# Sorted array into binary search tree

Tags: c++

So I have the following code, where I have created a constuctor, which initalizes a binary search tree using an array. The constructor passes the array, sorts it, and turns it into a binary function. In my main function, I have a menu with different cases to perform different actions on binary search trees. I have added a series of output statements to determine what's wrong and I believe it's a problem with my constructor when I call root = findMedian(...). Below I have the constructor, the findMedian function and the case in which it is called in the main. The program keeps aborting when I run it in the gdb. If anyone can help, I will greatly appreciate it, thanks!

```
//
//custom constructor that takes an array and turns it into a binary search tree
//
TreeType::TreeType( ItemType a[], int len )
{
        //sort array
        bubbleSort( a, len );
        //call recursive function
        int left = 0;
        int right = len - 1;
        cout << "in constructor, setting root." << endl;
        root = findMedian(a,left,right);
}
//function that finds median
TreeNode * TreeType::findMedian ( ItemType a[], int left, int right )
{
        if ( left > right )
                return NULL;

        TreeNode *tree = new TreeNode;
        int mid = (left+right)/2;
        cout << "Creating a treenode" << endl;
        cout << "a[mid} is: " << a[mid] << endl;
        tree -> info = a[mid];

        tree -> left = findMedian( a, left, mid - 1);//recursively call the left subtree
        tree -> right = findMedian(a, mid + 1, right );//recursively call the right subtree


        return tree;
}

//in main
case 'O':

                {
                        cout << "Enter a string: ";
                        cin >> words;
                        TreeType optimalTree( words, strlen(words));
                        optimalTree.Print();
                        cout << endl;
                        break;
                }

//sample run
Enter a string: YHGTRFB
len is: 7
in constructor, setting root.
left is: 0
right is: 6
Creating a treenode
a[mid} is: F
left is: 0
right is: 2
Creating a treenode
a[mid} is: F
left is: 0
right is: 0
Creating a treenode
a[mid} is: F
left is: 0
right is: -1
left is: 1
right is: 0
left is: 2
right is: 2
Creating a treenode
a[mid} is: F
left is: 2
right is: 1
left is: 3
right is: 2
left is: 4
right is: 6
Creating a treenode
a[mid} is: F
left is: 4
right is: 4
Creating a treenode
a[mid} is: F
left is: 4
right is: 3
left is: 5
right is: 4
left is: 6
right is: 6
Creating a treenode
a[mid} is: B
left is: 6
right is: 5
left is: 7
right is: 6
     F
   /   \
   F   F
 /   \   /   \
 F   F   F   B
```

Comment: What's the abort error message?

Comment: `TreeNode *tree = new TreeNode;` What is the use of creating `tree` again  when you are passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Later on, when I pass root through the constructor, root does not have any dynamically allocated memory yet, it's just a pointer. I think you're right in saying I do not need to pass it as a parameter, but I don't think that's reason my program is aborting

Comment: I removed the parameter, but I get a compiler error saying that tree was not declared in this scope and I have no clue why it's saying that

Comment: `ItemType a[], int len` - Perhaps `std::array` would be better

Comment: The error is because the scope of `tree` ends at the end of the `else` block.  You'd either need to move the `return` statement inside the `else` block or move the declaration of `tree` (but not the assignment part of that statement) above the `if` statement.

Comment: @ChynnaHernandez try putting `TreeNode *tree = new TreeNode;` outside `else`

Comment: I realized my silly mistake as soon as I wrote the comment. The program is now running without any core dumps or aborting of my program, but it sets the mid to the same character each time.

Comment: @ChynnaHernandez Are you sure about this.Since you are calling the function each time with different `left` and `right` you cannot get the same `mid`

Comment: I have included a sample run of the program in my edits. In the sample run, it continously sets the mid to F until the last function call